# Interface Implementation with generic type

Tags: c#, interface

I am trying to use this IRepository interface for all the classes. And to add other methods I have added IRoleRepository.
But I am failing to implement the IRoleRepository interface in my class.
How to implement the interface in class?[image]

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    public T Post(T t);
    public T Get();
    public T Get(T t);
    public T Put(T t);
    public T Delete(string id);
    public T Delete();
}
public interface IRoleRepository<T>:IRepository<T> where T:class
{
    public  T RoleExistsAsync(T roleName);

    public  T CreateRole(T user, T identityRole);

    public T GetRoles();

    public  T GetRoleById(T id);

    public  T UpdateRole(T identityRole);

    public  T DeleteRoleById(T identityRole);

    public  T GetClaimsByRole(T identityRole);

    public  T AddClaimToRole(T claim, T role);

    public  T RemoveClaimFromRole(T claim, T identityRole);
}



public class RoleManager : IRoleRepository<T> where T:class
{
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    public RoleManager( RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        this._roleManager = roleManager;
    }
            public async Task<bool> RoleExistsAsync(string roleName)
    {
        return await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);
    }
    public async Task<IdentityResult> CreateRole(ApplicationUser user, IdentityRole identityRole)
    {
        return  await _roleManager.CreateAsync(identityRole);
    }
    public IEnumerable<IdentityRole> GetRoles()
    {
        return _roleManager.Roles;
    }
    public async Task<IdentityRole> GetRoleById(string id)
    {
        return await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    }

}
```

Comment: `public interface IRoleRepository:IRepository<IdentityRole>` and `public class RoleRepository: IRoleRepository`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I am trying to keep IRoleRepository generic. Also IRepository will have some methods which will return IdentityResult. So it does not work

Comment: What is the purpose of keeping it generic? Your repository should be able to deal with specific type at one point... That's why you have a base repository which is generic and other repositories should deal with specific type. If you keep it generic then when will you decided which type of use with the repository?

Comment: Also you are implementing repository in RoleManager.. you should not do that.. You should have RoleRepository class Implementing IRoleRepository interface. RoleManager class should be dependent on the IRoleRepository. You have RoleManager class dependent on itself causing cyclic depdency.

Comment: I have understood your logic. If I make IRoleRepository non-generic. Can you show me how to implement those then? @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: If I make IRoleRepository non-generic. Can you show me how to implement those then? @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: You need to create a class RoleRepository which implements IRoleRepository interface  and implement all the methods in the class... What should be code inside the method bodies, that will be your our decision based on your requirement.

Comment: I want to keep IRepository as generic, and IRoleRepository non-generic. IRoleRepository  will inherit from IRepository. And RoleManager will implement IRoleRepository. In this way what would be the syntax of the classes for inheritance and implementation

Comment: https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/repository-pattern-in-aspnet-core/

Answer (score 1):

`IRepository<T>`, `T` in RoleManager only one type,

first way, change `IRoleRepository`

```cs
    public interface IRoleRepository<TResult, TUser, TRole> : IRepository<TResult>
        where TResult : class where TUser : class where TRole : class
    {
        public Task<bool> RoleExistsAsync(string roleName);

        public Task<TResult> CreateRole(TUser user, TRole identityRole);

        public IEnumerable<TRole> GetRoles();

        public Task<TRole> GetRoleById(string id);
    }
    }
```

`RoleManger`

```cs
public class RoleManager : IRoleRepository<IdentityResult, ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>
    {
        private readonly RoleManager _roleManager;
        public RoleManager(RoleManager roleManager)
        {
            this._roleManager = roleManager;
        }
        public async Task<bool> RoleExistsAsync(string roleName)
        {
            return await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);
        }
        public async Task<IdentityResult> CreateRole(ApplicationUser user, IdentityRole identityRole)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public IEnumerable<IdentityRole> GetRoles()
        {
            return _roleManager.Roles;
        }
        public async Task<IdentityRole> GetRoleById(string id)
        {
            return await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        }

    }
```

second way, add generic type in method like

```cs
 public Task<TResult> CreateRole<TUser, TRole>(TUser user, TRole identityRole);
```

Comment: I might have given a wrong example for what i need.   But you got it. Awesome solution, thanks.